# Twisted framework need some clarifications

Tags: python, twisted, factory

While I was going through code in twisted framework tutorials about 'writing servers', I came through following lines of code which made me confused.

```
class Chat(LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self,users):
        self.users = users

class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)
```

Anyone please explain how self.users in ChatFactory class gets updated whenever self.users in Chat class is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
f = ChatFactory()
p = f.buildProtocol(some_address)
```

the expressions `f.users` and `p.users` refer to the same dictionary.  This is because `ChatFactory.buildProtocol` passes `self.users` to the `Chat` initializer and the `Chat` initializer saves a reference to it.

Since it is the same dictionary, there is nothing that causes one to get updated when the other is updated because "one" and "the other" are actually the same thing.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Jean. Its very nice that i got response within a day.